# Sony VAIO mute button

Tags: vaio, sony

I installed ubuntu on my sony VAIO laptop. The laptop has two extra buttons near the power button - AV mode and mute (see the picture). The AV mode button works great (opens rhytmbox music player) but the mute button does not work (but it did work in the previously installed windows). How can make the mute button work?

[image: Vaio Laptop Image]

Comment: Did you look on Sony sites for software to support these special keys?

Comment: Yes but I did not find anything useful. The laptop is very old (it had windows vista installed) and is probably not supported anymore.

Comment: Oh well you can always create a mute shortcut key...

Comment: But how do I do that? I have just started using ubuntu so I do not know how to do such things.

Comment: @Petan Please review my answer below. If it works for you kindly click the check mark so others know it works and so your question comes off the "unanswered" list. If you find a better solution please post your own answer and mark it as solved by clicking the check mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move you mouse pointer to the `Launcher` and select the cog-wheel icon `System Settings`.

When the system settings panel appears select the icon `Keyboard`.

When the keyboard applet opens there are two tabs; `Typing` and `Shortcuts`. Select the shortcuts tab.

When the shortcuts tab opens the left pane lists the various categories you can choose from. Select the category `Sound and Media`.

Within the *Sound and Media* category click on the option `Volume mute` and you are prompted for a new accelerator key combination. For this tutorial hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys down at the same time and tap <kbd>M</kbd>.

Sample screen:

[image: Mute Shortcut]

From now on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will **mute** and **un-mute** your sound like a toggle switch. Your screen will also pop up a cool notification.

Comment: This worked perfectly !!!